# Formik InitialValues not changing to state defined values for Form React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, formik

I'm using an API call to return the values for an edit form. As it stands, formik is not populating the inputs with the values from the nested state object. I simply want to give the user the ability to edit/save their form and return back to the home screen. When I use value={this.state.application_form.first_name} for the input, it does set the value, but you cannot change it. **How do I populate the formik form with existing values using the initialValue & state props?**

I get an undefined error when using **state.application_form.info_attributes.attribute** or it doesn't load and set an attribute.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      application_form: {
        id: '',
        user_id: '',
        info_attributes: {
          prefix: '',
          first_name: ''
        }
      },
    };
  }

componentDidMount() {

this.getToken()
      .then(obj => axios.get(`http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/v1/retrieve_user/${obj.user_id}`, { headers: { Accept: 'application/json', 'X-User-Email': `${obj.email}`, 'X-User-Token': `${obj.authentication_token}` } }))
      .then(response => {

        this.setState({ user: JSON.stringify(response.data) });

        this.setState({ user_id: JSON.parse(this.state.user).id.toString() })

       fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/v1/get_application_form/${this.state.user_id}`)
       .then(response => response.json())
       .then(data =>
        
        this.setState({ 
        application_form: {
          id: String(data['id']),
          user_id: String(data['user_id']),
          personal_info_attributes: {
            prefix: String(data['info']['prefix']),
            first_name: String(data['info']['first_name']),
          }
        }
       }))
    
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });}
```

**Form.js**

```
 render() {
    return (
      <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="padding">
        <View style={{ paddingVertical: 5, paddingHorizontal: 14 }}>
          <View style={{ backgroundColor: '#fff', width: Dimensions.get('window').width * 0.9, minHeight: 50, padding: 2, borderColor: 'gray', borderRadius: 4, borderWidth: 1, height: Dimensions.get('window').height * 0.8 }}>
            
            <ScrollView>
              <Formik 
             
              enableReinitialize initialValues={{ application_form: { info_attributes: { prefix: '', first_name: '' }, user_id: this.userId(), id: this.application_form.id } }} onSubmit={(values) => {

                const { navigation } = this.props;

                return axios({
                  url: `http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/v1/application_forms`,
                  method: 'PUT',
                  data: values,
                }).then(response => {
                  navigation.navigate('Dashboard')
                }).catch(err => {
                  showMessage({
                    message: "Unable to submit!",
                    description: "Testing",
                    type: 'danger'
                  })
                })
              }}>
              
                {props => (
                    
                  <View style={{ padding: 1 }}>
 
                    <Text>Prefix</Text>
                    <TextInput style={styles.input} onChangeText={text => props.setFieldValue('application_form.info_attributes.prefix', text)} />

                    <Text>First Name</Text>
                    <TextInput style={styles.input} onChangeText={text => props.setFieldValue('application_form.info_attributes.first_name', text)} />
                    
                    <Text>Middle Name</Text>
                    <TextInput style={styles.input} onChangeText={text => props.setFieldValue('application_form.info_attributes.middle_name', text)} />

            
                    <Button onPress={props.handleSubmit} title="Submit" />
                  </View>
                )}
              </Formik>
            </ScrollView>
          </View>
        </View>
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    )
  }
```

Comment: Where is the `state` that you are trying to access? Add it to your example

Comment: updated the question. Using a class component.